# How to get the variables of the select field in the psql client of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

in psql client: run

`select pg_backend_pid() ospid \gset`

`\echo :ospid`

this can get ospid value;

but : I want echo ospid col  value to file

`\! echo 'a' :ospid 'b' > /tmp/test.log`

how can i fix it ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) says:

> Unlike most other meta-commands, the entire remainder of the line is always taken to be the argument(s) of `\!`, and neither variable interpolation nor backquote expansion are performed in the arguments.

You can work around that with `\g`:

```
test=> \pset format unaligned
Output format is unaligned.
test=> \pset tuples_only
Tuples only is on.
test=> SELECT pg_backend_pid() ospid \gset
test=> SELECT 'a ' || :ospid  || ' b' \g /tmp/test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Laurenz Albe.

My goal is to set the terminal title.

I work around  with this

```
\pset tuples_only on
\pset border 0

SELECT user,pg_backend_pid() ospid  \g  ./_ospid.log

\echo '******** ospid:=[':ospid']   user:=[':user']********'

\! echo -ne '\033]0;'`cat ./_ospid.log`'\007' ;


\pset tuples_only off
\pset border 2
```